# Trouble creating switch statement

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++, and I am having trouble completing an assignment.  I need to switch this if statement to a switch statement, but I am totally lost on how to do it since the number must be an integer.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

See below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //declare named constants and variables
  const double RATE1 = .02;
  const double RATE2 = .05;
  double sales       = 0.0;
  double commission  = 0.0;

  //get input item
  cout << "Enter the sales amount: "; 
  cin >> sales; 

  //calculate commission
  if (sales <= 15000.0)
{
    commission = sales * RATE1;
else
    commission = sales * RATE2;

 }
//end if

//display commission
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
  cout << "Commission: $" << commission << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}   //end of main function
```

Comment: If in this code is not switchable to switch, pun intended.

Comment: @SergeyA Times when \`ticks\` would be useful. :)

Comment: In fact @SergeyA is the only one being right about answering this question.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood your assignment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could do something like this, similar to NathanOliver's answer without a new function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //declare named constants and variables
  const double RATE1 = .02;
  const double RATE2 = .05;
  double sales       = 0.0;
  double commission  = 0.0;

  //get input item
  cout << "Enter the sales amount: "; 
  cin >> sales; 

  //calculate commission

  bool lessthan = sales <= 15000.0;

  switch (lessthan) 
  {
      case true: 
          commission = sales * RATE1;
          break;

      case false: 
        commission = sales * RATE2;
        break;

      default: 
        break;        
  }

//display commission
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
  cout << "Commission: $" << commission << endl;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}   //end of main function`
```

Comment: `default` is unreachable here. No need to include it.

Comment: @erip - True, just been a habit of mine to always add it.

Comment: @SergeyA - It's a different way of doing things, feel free to flag if you think it should be deleted.

Comment: How is it different from already posted answer by @JohnSensebe?

Comment: @SergeyA - If you hadn't noticed, mine was only 5 minutes after. It wasn't there when I first clicked add answer. Anyway, this is a pointless argument, I'm going to get on with my day. You're welcome to reply but I won't.

Comment: @robert.woods Mind to add some reasoning for `default: 
        break; ` ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - There is no need for it, just a bad habit of mine to always end a `switch` with a `default`

Comment: robert.woods, that worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This is not feasibly possible to do. `switch` requires integral equality, your code checks for lesser than  on a double number.

The unfeasible option would be to convert your double to integer with lost precision and than list all 15000 options as case labels. Not feasible at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you use gcc then you can use case ranges: [Case Ranges](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Case-Ranges.html), but this works IMHO for integral data types, I am not sure about doubles.

But don't forget, this is only the extension of the compiler. I also heard something similar was introduced with C++11, but I am not sure there.

Comment: Why are you spreading the knowledge of this terrible feature?

Comment: The topic is not about best practices ha-ha. Even in spite I totally agree with your dislike this feature, it may fit to the task ))

Answer (score 1):

You can technically do it in this horrible way:

```
//calculate commission
switch (sales <= 15000.0)
{
case true: 
    commission = sales * RATE1;
    break;
default:
    commission = sales * RATE2;
}
```

But never, *ever* do this in real code.

Comment: hahahaha, I like this. I want to upvote it, but I don't want people to think this is good.

Comment: Well, I do stress how one shouldn't do this. I think the assignment is flawed, though, and deserves this kind of answer.

Comment: I can only hope the teacher is looking for a negative answer on the assignment: "Sorry sir, this can't be done using a switch" (with bonus points for students adding "...without using hideous constructs like <the above example>").

Answer (score 0):

As [SergeyA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5245033/sergeya) pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34771114/4342498) this is feasible as it is a huge range of cases.

If it absolutely needs to have a switch statement then we can cheat and have a function that returns true or false and then switch on the result of that function

```
bool is_less(double amount)
{
    return amount < 15000.0;
}

//...

switch (is_less(sales))
{
    case true: commission = sales * RATE1; break;
    case false: commission = sales * RATE2; break;
}
```

Comment: Not only it is cheating, it's cheating with overhead. You can simply use switch on the in-site comparison.

Comment: Still an interesting solution, though.